# Atmosphere - How to push some mensagem from Java Code?

Tags: javascript, websocket, comet, long-polling, atmosphere

I have some examples of Atmosphere working fine, but now I have the necessity to push some messages from my Java Code without firing the messages through jsp + javascript.

For example,I have this code:

My JSP:

```
<form action="${ctx}/enviamsg" method="post">
  <select name="nome">
     <option value="gustavo">Gustavo </option>
     <option value="joao"> João </option>
     <option value="ze"> Zé </option>
  </select>
  <input name="msg">
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

My Java Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enviamsg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String envia(final AtmosphereResource event, @RequestParam String nome, @RequestParam String msg) throws IOException{

    Broadcaster bd = lookupBroadcaster(nome);
    bd.broadcast(msg);
    return "envia";

}

private Broadcaster lookupBroadcaster(String name) {

    Broadcaster broadcaster = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault(). lookup(name);
    return broadcaster;
}
```

But nothink happen on my jsp that was subscribed on this broadcaster. When I broadcast my message. How could I push my messages Atmosphere client (javascript) ?